# Apps Script copy data in to formatted area?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm sending data from an app to a google sheet and then trying to format the data. If I pre-format the cells in anticipation of the data, the rows of data end up being appended below the last formatted row. I'm also trying to base other cells off the anticipated data that is being imported, but the rows get appended below the last row with data, even if it's not in the way. For example, if I'm always importing 1 row and 3 columns at a time, I would like to prefill column 4 onwards withe formulas and have my data slot into the same row. Is this possible with google apps script? Or is the only way to have the row of data appended after the last row in the sheet? Ideally, I'd like it to be the first available row with the first 3 columns empty.

Comment: It sounds like append is not a good option then.  It would be helpful to see some images of the Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Using `appendRow` when you want to that the new row gets the same formatting of the above rows is "tricky". The safe way to go is to use the script to set the format of the appended row. One way to do this is by using [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed) with `SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT`